# Facebook Graph API Public Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way I can search for all public chechkins in facebook using graph api , or maybe checkins are not a part of the accessible public data category ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read all information about a checkin from his CHECKIN_ID. You can´t get all checkins available via graph api, you need each CHECKIN_ID in order to get information of each one.

Read more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/)

Also take into account, that Checkin objects are deprecated by facebook, instead use Post Objects with a location attached

Comment: I don't need to get information about cerain chechkin . 
Facebook graph api let you pull public posts, I wonder if there's any option to get information about public checkins / public places where people have been to .

Comment: You can get only this information from you and your friends with: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin (and also limited for a certain position or place_id)

Comment: You still don't get me right. Facebook graph api allows you to pull PUBLIC INFORMATION such as post , also from users that are not your friend . This kind of information is available from any user as long as his user information is not private.
My question is whether there's a way to pull PUBLIC checkins information ?